# Difference between lazy minting in OpenSea and Rarible

Tags: nft, gas-price, mint, opensea

[Rarible](https://rarible.com) allows us to publish gas-free NFTs through lazy minting while [OpenSea](https://opensea.io) requires an initial gas fee (for Ethereum), after which all subsequent NFTs are published for free.

1. After paying the initial OpenSea fee, are all new NFTs minted on the blockchain directly or are they lazy minted like on Rarible?
2. Without paying this fee, I am still able to receive offers on my NFT, although I cannot set the price myself until I do pay it. Is publishing on OpenSea without paying the fee the same as lazy minting on Rarible?

Answer (score 0):

Answer of 1: Yes, it is minted in blockchain. You could test to mint somethings using testnets.opensea.io. It will ask for some gas fee during the 1st time listing but you could use the fake ETH to overcome that.

Answer of 2: I have no idea about Rarible, but I can see without paying the 1st gas fee, I can still see it in blockchain and include the NFT in metamask wallet. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Opensea creates a proxy contract for every address it interacts to as to save the gas fees during lazy minting. It is one time cost. Lazy minting basically stores the NFT details into the external server of opensea and not mints on blockchain when user places it to list. NFT is minted to blockchain when buyers buys the NFT from opensea.